# Url rewrite not working properly in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have installed wordpress in cakephp's webroot folder. 
Now my blog is opening properly with  "http://smghut.com/blog/" but when i am typing "http://smghut.com/blog" (ie, without slash(/)) at last it redirecting to "http://www.smghut.com/app/webroot/blog/".

Comment: post the cakephp `.htaccess` file

Comment: @machineaddict  

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /blog/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your defining to different rules to same directory. its not possible. better to upload your blog in a separate sub directory. blog.something.com

Answer (score 0):

In your wordpress root folder. change .htaccess as per below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /blog/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```